# Pygame Fullscreen Window Control

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, fullscreen

I am making a game using pygame. I have set the window so it is fullscreen using 'flag=pygame.FULLSCREEN' but there are no controls to exit the program or minimise it like a normal window would have in the top right corner. Does anyone know how to get this working? I have included the ability to exit by the escape button but I also want the cross at the top.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
BLUE = (0,0,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
size = (1920,1080)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,flags=pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
characterPic = pygame.image.load("average_joe1.png").convert()
carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            carryOn = False
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,[55,200,100,70],0)
    screen.blit(characterPic, (20, 500))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(75)
pygame.quit()`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please attach to your question some code?

Answer (score 1):

That is something that every fullscreen program has to manage itself. Typically a program will use the `Esc` key or something to trigger exit or change from full screen to window.

You have to deal with that in the program.

Comment: The OP could also add their own `[x]` custom graphic button if they really need it.  Personally I think just handling Esc as you suggest is enough.